# How to convert JSON data to a map of custom objects in typescript

Tags: typescript, dictionary

For this raw data (originally a JSON file and imported by `import * as raw_data from './json_file.json'`):

```
let raw_data: object = {"a": {"name": "Name a", "desc": "Description a"}, "b": {"name": "Name b", "desc": "Description b"} }
```

I would like to retrieve a map of keys (as strings) and the custom objects of interface `AnObject`

```
interface AnObject {
    name: string;
    description: string;
}
```

in typescript. How can I do that?

I have tried

```
let myObject: Map<string, AnObject> = raw_data as Map<string, AnObject>;
```

or

```
let myObject: Map<string, AnObject> = <Map<string, AnObject>>raw_data
```

but with small success: The object remains an `object` and `myObject.size` is undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying only type level modifications, but an object is actually different from a Map after transpilation, so you need to create it like this :

```
let myObject: Map<string, AnObject> = new Map(Object.entries(raw_data));
```